# How do I tell Octave where to find functions without picking up other files?

Tags: scripting, path, octave

I've written an octave script, `hello.m`, which calls `subfunc.m`, and which takes a single input file, a command line argument, `data.txt`, which it loads with `load(argv(){1})`.

If I put all three files in the same directory, and call it like

```
./hello.m data.txt
```

then all is well.

But if I've got another `data.txt` in another directory, and I want to run my script on it, and I call

```
../helloscript/hello.m data.txt
```

this fails because `hello.m` can't find `subfunc.m`.

If I call

```
octave --path "../helloscript" ../helloscript/hello.m data.txt
```

then that seems to work fine.

The problem is that if I don't have a `data.txt` in the directory, then the script will pick up any `data.txt` that is lying around in `../helloscript`.

This seems a bit fragile. Is there any way to tell octave, preferably in the script itself, to get subfunctions from the same directory as the script, but to get everything else relative to the current directory.

The best robust solution I can think of at the moment is to inline the subfunction in the script, which is a bit nasty.

Is there a good way to do this, or is it just a thorny problem that will cause occasional hard to find problems and can't be avoided?

Is this in fact just a general problem with scripting languages that I've just never noticed before? How does e.g. python deal with it?

It seems like there should be some sort of library-load-path that can be set without altering the data-load-path.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all your subfunctions to your program file is not nasty at all. Why would you think so? It is perfectly normal to have function definitions in your script. The only language I know that does not do this is Matlab but that's just braindead.

The other alternative you have is to check that the input file argument, `data.txt` exists. Like so:

```
fpath = argv (){1};
[info, err, msg] = stat (fpath);
if (err)
    error ("could not stat `%s' : %s", fpath, msg);
endif
## continue your script knowing the file exists
```

But really, I would recommend you to use both. Add your subfunctions in your main program, the only reason to have it on separate file is if you plan on sharing with other programs, and always check input arguments.